# Why we can't use execAndWait interceptor using ServletActionContext?

Tags: java, struts2, thread-local, struts2-interceptors, actioncontext

I have to use loading bar on selected actions in Struts2, & am using `ServletActionContext`, but getting `NullPointerException`.

```
ActionContext.getContext().get(org.apache.struts2.StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);
```

If I remove `execAndWait` interceptor from xml configuration file, it works fine.

Some people suggested me to use `SessionAware`. Why so ?

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The `ActionContext` is `ThreadLocal` and it doesn't have a request object when you run a background thread via [`execAndWait` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/execute-and-wait-interceptor.html).

If you use `SessionAware`, then you should have [`servletConfig` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/servlet-config-interceptor.html) on the stack to be able to set the session object to your action before the action is executed.

**Solution:** if you can get `ServletRequestAware` to set a request object to the action and use  `servletConfig` interceptor prior the `execAndWait` interceptor in the stack. If you need to create a custom stack you should keep the order.